# ASP Membership Profile in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, membership-provider, asp.net-profiles

I am trying to replicate the ASP Membership Profile functionality in ColdFusion. Basically I want to be able to get and save the property values.

To understand my basic need, I have the following:

```
table: aspnet_Profile
UserID | PropertyNames | PropertyValuesString |...| LastUpdatedDate
xyzxyz | FirstName:S:0:5:LastName:S:5:1: | SollyM |...| 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Now using ASP.net, using `profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName")` will return `Solly` and `profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName")` will return `M`.

The interpretation of the PropertyNames is:

```
LastName => PropertyName
S => String
5 => Starting Position
1 => Length
```

To save the new `LastName` you use `profile.SetPropertyValue("LastName","de Mots")` and the table will be as below:

```
table: aspnet_Profile
UserID | PropertyNames | PropertyValuesString |...| LastUpdatedDate
xyzxyz | FirstName:S:0:5:LastName:S:5:7: | Sollyde Mots |...| 2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

How can I replicate this in ColdFusion?

I have been trying this for over 2 days.

Comment: Is that profile data stored in a database?

Comment: Yes. That was me trying to replicate the `aspnet_Profile` table in MSSQL. The `PropertyNames` and `PropertyValueString` are of `NTEXT` type. `UserID` is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and `LastUpdatedDate` is a `DateTime` (which I am not worried about). The "`...`" represent a column I am not using.

Comment: ColdFusion has [.NET integration](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-789c.html) if you can leverage that. Or are you getting away from the .NET altogether?

Comment: This is great. No I am not running away from it. In fact, I am writing the .NET version of our In-House CF System and all Membership-related functions in .NET I must replicate in CF without using additional tables.

Comment: I can't seem to use the profile methods from .NET. 

    100 : <cfobject type=".NET" name="profileBase" 
    101 :             class="System.Web.Profile"> 
    102 : <cfset profile = profileBase.Create("Username") >)

Error:

Class `System.Web.Profile` not found in the specified assembly list.

I have tried this with the `class="System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase"` first.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `assembly` and pointing it to the correct DLL? Read about it at the link that I supplied earlier.

Comment: I keep getting the same error and this time I even specified the actual assembly file.<br />
    100 : <h3>.NET Test</h3>
    101 : <cfobject type=".NET" name="membership" 
    102 :             class="System.Web.Security" assembly="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll"> 
    103 : <cfset user = membership.GetUser("Username") >
    104 : <cfoutput>UserID = #user.ProviderUserKey#</cfoutput>
<br />
Please Help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32318/discussion-between-solly-m-and-miguel-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally wrote my own CFC and can be downloaded from http://collabedit.com/7xmca

There are 3 functions:

1. `PasswordEncrypt` => This is one if the queries I had to deal with when Hashing the Password in CFM to match that of Membership.
2. `ProfileGet("UserId","PropertyName")` => returns the value of the property name.
3. `ProfileSet("UserId","PropertyName","NewPropertyValue")` => updates the `PropertyName` with the `NewPropertyValue`.

Note that the `ProfileGet` and `ProfileSet` only deals with the `PropertyValuesString` and not the `PropertyValuesBinary` of the Profile. You can extend this to get that much.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. In the final version, just be sure to `var/local` scope *all* function local variables. Otherwise, you will run into weird threading problems if the cfc is stored in a shared scope. Also, be sure to use `cfqueryparam` to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Can you please access the link provided in my answer and update the code? You won't have to login. It will ask for your name and email I think, and you will be able to edit the file.

Comment: I was going to do that, but .. I do not have access to the sql tables this week and did not want to break the working code with an inadvertent typo ;).